# Restablecer contraseña cuenta Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo un restablecimiento de contraseña con laravel, Todo  funciona bien en cuanto se envía el email para poder acceder al Link y de acuerdo al token hacer el cambió de contraseña.

Entonces, entra al sitio: pero ahora viene un error que no me había percatado. Cuando se cierra sesión e intento acceder con la contraseña  nueva que puse, no me deja.

e inclusive en un módulo cuando quiero hacer cambió de contraseña, pues me regresa que la contraseña no es la correcta.

quiero pensar que el problema es cuando se hace el restablecimiento de contraseña, No se ni por donde ver el problema.

Comment: Está utilizando el sistema de autenticación de Laravel? ¿Sí es así, modificó los archivos? ¿Cuáles? Tal y como está su pregunta no se puede determinar donde podría estar tal "fallo" .

Comment: @Dev.Joel lo que pasa es que no me había percatado. solo utilize el Make:auth . E hice un modulo para el cambió de clave. pero aún así, Cuando se restablece la contraseña e intento acceder por segunda vez con esa clave. No me deja

Comment: En su bd como se guarda la nueva contraseña? hasheada o en texto plano.

Comment: Hash. inclusive supuse que algomalo estaría pasando, pero le quite el hash y si es la clave que es.pero entonces, porque no la reconce? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al momento de iniciar mi proyecto utilice los comandos de

```
php artisan make:auth
```

e hice un modulo para cambiar mi contraseña cuando estaba el usuario adentro del sistema, hasta ahí todo bien.

pero cuando hice eso, quite una  Encriptación, Ya que al usar vue y mi controlador por aparte, si no lo quitaba. cuando se registraba una nueva cuenta, lo que hacía es que entonces habría doble encriptación.

e hice un mutador el cual  todo funcionaba perfecto, pero me percate que solo funcionaba para nuevas cuentas.

pero cuando quise restablecer una nueva contraseña, olvide quita la otra encriptación. así que entonces lo que estaba pasando es que estaba encriptando doblemente

en el restablecimiento de contraseña  y enseguida el mutador nuevamente estaba encriptando.

**en resumen, solo quite una encriptación y me quede con la del mutador.**

Answer (score -1):

si el proyecto es medianamente reciente, creo que  partir de la v5.0 del framework ya viene el comando make:auth en el artisan

proba desde la linea de comandos

```
php artisan make:auth
```

y te arma el modelo, el controlador y todos los comandos solo sin necesidad de armar a mano todo el tema de recuperacion de contraseña y demas